# Can Truecaller get caller ID on 2G connection?

Tags: mobile-network, 2g, truecaller

Truecaller emphasizes that it requires 3G/WiFi connection in order to tell caller ID. Does this mean that if I'm in an area where only 2G is available and no WiFi is available, Truecaller cannot get a caller ID for me?

Answer (score 1):

1. People install the Truecaller app.
2. The app uploads all your contacts' names, mobile numbers, photos, and other details to its server.
3. The app queries its server with the number which is calling you and gets the person's name and displays it.

So, Truecaller needs internet access to function whether through the WiFi/GSM/GPRS/EDGE, etc. network. So, when you are in a location with only 2G and no WiFi, Truecaller cannot get a caller ID.

Comment: AFAIK, 2G also provides mobile data, are you sure it can't get a caller ID?